# How to build python class structure for matplotlib to export ot .exe with cx_freeze?

Tags: python-3.x, cx-freeze

I built a code to generate and play random musical notes. It is working great within python, but I would like to make it into an .exe stand alone program, so people without python can use it. I show an image below of the output. It creates a matplotlib figure with a 'TkAgg' backend. There are 5 buttons and an user entry box that all work.

I used cx_freeze to try to package it, and I worked through all of the errors. I also got some of the examples to work. I can see the the build folder is getting the 4 Images and many .wav files I need to draw the musical staff and play the notes. One error showed that the .exe tried to run my code, because it couldn't find the .wav files). I changed how I specified where they were for the .exe. But now when I run the .exe nothing happens.

Unfortunately my code is  a monstrosity. It's messy, and somewhat long (750 lines if you count white space). The .py file I am trying to write to the .exe is Interval_Trainer_v1_1.py. It can be found [here](https://github.com/Bcubrich/Music-Interval-Trainer).

Because it works in python, but not in the .exe, I thought it might have to do with my ignorance of how to use classes in conjunction with plotting well. Basically I call the class, and then initialize a bunch of things so I can refer to them later. That allows me to delete notes I've plotted before, old answers, etc.

How can I practice building up 'TkAgg' backended figures that will execute properly after cf_freeze? I feel like I need to start with some basic ideas and build up to my application, which is fairly complex.

One note, I do use pygame for the sounds.

Here is my setup file:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import os
os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY']=r'C:\Users\Bart\Anaconda3\tcl\tcl8.6'
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY']=r'C:\Users\Bart\Anaconda3\tcl\tk8.6'

import sys
base = None
if sys.platform == 'win32':
    base = 'Win32GUI'
additional_mods = ['numpy.core._methods', 'numpy.lib.format',"matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg", 'matplotlib.pyplot', 'matplotlib.image', 'matplotlib.widgets']
setup(
    name = "Interval Trainer",
    version = "1.0.0",
    author = "Bart",
    author_email = "bcubrich@gmail.com",
    options = {"build_exe": {'includes': additional_mods,"packages":["pygame","tkinter",'random'],
                         "include_files": [
                         'Images/F cleff 8vb.png', 'Images/F cleff.png',
                         'Images/G cleff 8vb.png', 'Images/G cleff.png',
                         'Pitches/A#1.wav', 'Pitches/A#2.wav', 'Pitches/A#3.wav',
                         'Pitches/A#4.wav', 'Pitches/A#5.wav', 'Pitches/A1.wav',
                         'Pitches/A2.wav', 'Pitches/A3.wav', 'Pitches/A4.wav',
                         'Pitches/A5.wav', 'Pitches/Ab1.wav', 'Pitches/Ab2.wav',
                         'Pitches/Ab3.wav', 'Pitches/Ab4.wav', 'Pitches/B#2.wav',
                         'Pitches/B#3.wav', 'Pitches/B#4.wav', 'Pitches/B1.wav',
                         'Pitches/B2.wav', 'Pitches/B3.wav', 'Pitches/B4.wav',
                         'Pitches/B5.wav', 'Pitches/Bb1.wav', 'Pitches/Bb2.wav',
                         'Pitches/Bb3.wav', 'Pitches/Bb4.wav', 'Pitches/C#2.wav',
                         'Pitches/C#3.wav', 'Pitches/C#4.wav', 'Pitches/C#5.wav',
                         'Pitches/C2.wav', 'Pitches/C3.wav', 'Pitches/C4.wav',
                         'Pitches/C5.wav', 'Pitches/C6.wav', 'Pitches/D#2.wav',
                         'Pitches/D#3.wav', 'Pitches/D#4.wav', 'Pitches/D#5.wav',
                         'Pitches/D2.wav', 'Pitches/D3.wav', 'Pitches/D4.wav',
                         'Pitches/D5.wav', 'Pitches/Db1.wav', 'Pitches/Db2.wav',
                         'Pitches/Db3.wav', 'Pitches/Db4.wav', 'Pitches/E#2.wav',
                         'Pitches/E#3.wav', 'Pitches/E#4.wav', 'Pitches/E1.wav',
                         'Pitches/E2.wav', 'Pitches/E3.wav', 'Pitches/E4.wav',
                         'Pitches/E5.wav', 'Pitches/Eb2.wav', 'Pitches/Eb3.wav',
                         'Pitches/Eb4.wav', 'Pitches/F#1.wav', 'Pitches/F#2.wav',
                         'Pitches/F#3.wav', 'Pitches/F#4.wav', 'Pitches/F#5.wav',
                         'Pitches/F1.wav', 'Pitches/F2.wav', 'Pitches/F3.wav',
                         'Pitches/F4.wav', 'Pitches/F5.wav', 'Pitches/G#1.wav',
                         'Pitches/G#2.wav', 'Pitches/G#3.wav', 'Pitches/G#4.wav',
                         'Pitches/G#5.wav', 'Pitches/G1.wav', 'Pitches/G2.wav',
                         'Pitches/G3.wav', 'Pitches/G4.wav', 'Pitches/G5.wav',
                         'Pitches/Gb1.wav', 'Pitches/Gb2.wav', 'Pitches/Gb3.wav',
                         'Pitches/Gb4.wav']}},
    executables = [Executable("Interval_trainer_v1_1.py", base=base)],
    )
```

[Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nlLz.png)

Any help is appreciate.

Comment: One of the things that is very helpful when using an .exe build is to launch the exe in the windows (in my case) command prompt. This will allow for the printing of python errors which won't close when the app closes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the `matplotlib` user interfaces examples [embedding_in_tk](https://matplotlib.org/1.2.1/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk.html) and [embedding_in_tk2](https://matplotlib.org/1.2.1/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk2.html) to practice building up `TkAgg` backended figures.