# How to build matplotlib, tkinter backended, GUI that works with cx-freeze?

Tags: python, exe, cx-freeze

I am trying to make an exe. I have a more complicated program that works very well for me, which I already posted about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52789008/how-to-build-python-class-structure-for-matplotlib-to-export-ot-exe-with-cx-fre). I tried to simplify this example down to the minimum number of elements and test. Basically, I need a program that can create a plot, and add and remove things from that plot with buttons. This works fine when I run it on my python IDE, but when I create and .exe with freeze, nothing happens when I double click it. The same is true of my more complex program.

Here is the code I am trying to make into and .exe as a test (I save this code as 'Test1.py'):

```
#Filename should be Test1.py for this
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Button


class plotter(object):

    staff, staff_ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 4))
    staff_ax.axhline(y=1, color='0', linestyle='-')
    item_1,=staff_ax.plot(0,0,alpha=0)
    staff_ax.set_ylim(-15,25)
    staff_ax.set_xlim(0,10)

    error_1=0
    pressed=0

    def add_item(self, event):
        if self.pressed==0:
            self.item_1,=self.staff_ax.plot(5,5, marker='o')
            self.staff.show()
            self.pressed=1

    def del_item(self, event):
        try:
            self.item_1
            self.item_1.remove()

        except ValueError:
            self.error_1+=1
        self.staff.show()
        self.pressed=0

callback = plotter()
b1_loc = plt.axes([0.1, 0.05, 0.2, 0.075])
b2_loc = plt.axes([0.3, 0.05, 0.2, 0.075])
b_show = Button(b1_loc, 'Plot')
b_show.on_clicked(callback.add_item)
b_del = Button(b2_loc, 'Remove')
b_del.on_clicked(callback.del_item)
```

And I use the following as my setup file (setup.py):

```
#Filename should be setup.py
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import os
os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY']=r'C:\Users\Bart\Anaconda3\tcl\tcl8.6'
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY']=r'C:\Users\Bart\Anaconda3\tcl\tk8.6'

import sys
base = 'Win32GUI'
if sys.platform == 'win32':
    base = 'Win32GUI'
additional_mods = ['numpy.core._methods', 'numpy.lib.format',
                   "matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg", 'matplotlib.pyplot', 
                   'matplotlib.image', 'matplotlib.widgets']
setup(
    name = "TEst1",
    version = "1.0.0",
    author = "Bart",
    author_email = "******@gmail.com",
    options = {"build_exe": {'includes': 
        additional_mods,"packages":["pygame","tkinter",'random', 'matplotlib'],}},
    executables = [Executable("Test1.py", base=base)],
    )
```

When I run

```
python setup.py build
```

It runs fine, and creates a filestructure 'build' that contains 'Test1.exe'. When I run Test1.exe though, nothing happens. No errors, just nothing. The code in 'Test1.exe' is the simplest version of my coed I can think of to test. I already tested some of the samples available at cx-freeze to make sure it was installed and running properly on my machine, and it is.

Does anyone know how I might be able to write this so it can run as an exe? My suspicion is that I need to send my plot to a TK window. In other words, wrap my code in root.TK() at the beginning, and root.mainloop() at the end, but I don't know how.

When working, the output of Test1.py should be an interactive plot that looks like this:

[image: Output]

And the button 'Plot' adds the dot seen in the image, while 'Remove' removes it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the `matplotlib` user interfaces examples [embedding_in_tk](https://matplotlib.org/1.2.1/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk.html) and [embedding_in_tk2](https://matplotlib.org/1.2.1/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk2.html) describing how to send a plot to a TK window.